# How to get current month in CalendarView?

Tags: android

I'm using `CalendarView` class to insert a calendar in my app. I've done it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_userCalendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With this, I can see the calendar like this:

[image]

And all months are seen!
I tried to filter by current month programmatically like this:

```
calendar = (CalendarView) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.calendar_userCalendar);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int daysInMonth = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
calendar.setMaxDate(daysInMonth);
```

But it still shows all months... How can I set calendar to show only current month and filter events by this month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the starting and ending date of month and then set it to your calendar object to display

```
public Pair<Date, Date> getDateRange() {
    Date begining, end;

    {
        Calendar calendar = getCalendarForNow();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setTimeToBeginningOfDay(calendar);
        begining = calendar.getTime();
    }

    {
        Calendar calendar = getCalendarForNow();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setTimeToEndofDay(calendar);
        end = calendar.getTime();
    }

    return Pair.create(begining, end);
}

private static Calendar getCalendarForNow() {
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    return calendar;
}

private static void setTimeToBeginningOfDay(Calendar calendar) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
}

private static void setTimeToEndofDay(Calendar calendar) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
}
```

You can get the starting and ending date of the month by using the above code ]and then you can set the starting and ending date of the month to preview

Comment: How to use the pair method?